# Rounding a date with r

Tags: r, rounding

I have this date format "***March 12th 2019, 15: 08: 27.174***" and I want to round it up, so as to keep that hours and minutes.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `ceiling_date` from `lubridate` after converting it to datetime

```
library(lubridate)
ceiling_date(mdy_hms("March 12th 2019, 15: 08: 27.174"), unit = "minutes")
#[1] "2019-03-12 15:09:00 UTC"
```

Or if you just want to `round` use `round_date`

```
round_date(mdy_hms("March 12th 2019, 15: 08: 27.174"), unit = "minutes")
#[1] "2019-03-12 15:08:00 UTC"
```

which can also be done with base R

```
round(as.POSIXct("March 12th 2019, 15: 08: 27.174", 
                format = "%B %dth %Y, %H:%M:%S"), "mins")

#[1] "2019-03-12 15:08:00 +08"
```

Comment: this is the error message that appears when running the command                              Error in library(lubridate) : 
no package named 'lubridate' is found

Comment: we need to install it first do `install.packages("lubridate")` and then run the command.